# Merging polygons - Merge feature failed error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, merge

[image]

I'd like to make the two adjacent polygons become one, I tried to merge the two polygons of Hackney and City of London as below, but just keep getting the error "Merge feature failed"

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Lots of possible causes, but my bet would be on invalid geometry -- Do a Check Geometry and/or Repair Geometry first. You may need to make sure they don't overlap.

Comment: Are you really using ArcMap 10.0 to try and do this?